# How to get fixed sizes on images retrieved from the database?

Tags: php, html, css

I'm using PHP & MYSQL to get images and other text info from my database to show on my page. This is working fine. The problem is the pictures stored in the database are different sizes. So i have applied some HTML & CSS to get a fixed size of the pictures to display on my page. Unfortunately this isn't working. Here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><b>The title</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="foto_style"><img src="http:/mypage.com/pictures/mypic.png" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

**CSS:**

```
 .foto_style{width: 50px; height:50px;}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your CSS to:

```
.foto_style img {
  width: 50px; 
  height:50px;
}​
```

Comment: @the_boy_za because your selector (`.foto_style`) is applied to the `td` rather than the image that is a child of the `td`.